# Better code layout for Anorm Parsers

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm using Scala, Anorm, and the Play2 Framework to retrieve data from SQL tables. In many places I have code like this:

```
val emailViewRecordParser: RowParser[EmailViewRecord] = {
  str( "sfname" ) ~
  str( "slname" ) ~
  str( "practice_name" ) ~
  str( "email" ) ~
  str( "phone_area_code" ) map {
    case
      subscriberFirstName ~
      subscriberLastName ~
      practiceName ~
      subscriberEmail ~
      phoneAreaCode
      deviceAddress =>
      EmailViewRecord(
        subscriberFirstName,
        subscriberLastName,
        practiceName,
        subscriberEmail,
        phoneAreaCode
      )
  }
}
```

This is difficult to manage, since it's very easy to mess up the parameter ordering/length. Ideally we would be able to write something along the lines of:

```
val emailViewRecordParser: RowParser[EmailViewRecord] = {
 EmailViewRecord(
  str( "sfname" ) map { subscriberFirstName } subscriberFirstName,
  str( "slname" ) map { subscriberLastName } subscriberLastName,
  str( "practice_name" ) map {  practiceName } practiceName,
  str( "email" ) map { subscriberEmail } subscriberEmail,
  str( "phone_area_code" ) map { phoneAreaCode } phoneAreaCode
 )
}
```

What's a nice functional way to achieve a layout along those lines? Also, the 'str' function at the beginning could be int, date, etc. so the first function needs to be specific to every line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with line parsers is that they are intended to be used on a whole line.  I suggest that your problem is not with that, though, but is with repeatedly giving gigantic names that clutter everything so much that you can't pay attention to the logic any more.  Look at this:

```
str("sfname") ~ str("slname") ~ str("practice_name") ~
str("email")  ~ str("phone_area_code") map {
  case a~b~c~d~e => EmailViewRecord(a,b,c,d,e)
}
```

It's way harder to get that wrong.  If you feel this is inadequately documented, add comments on the parser lines like so:

```
val parser =
  str("sfname") ~          // Subscriber first name
  ...
  str("phone_area_code")   // You'll never guess that this is the area code.

parser map { case a~b~c~d~e => EmailViewRecord(a,b,c,d,e) }
```

There are other possible solutions that involve a lot more tooling, but I'm not sure in your case it's worth the effort.

Comment: We have many tables with 15+ columns, so I would still end up with long lines like:
      case a~b~c~d~e~f~g~h~i~j~k~l~m~n => EmailViewRecord(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n)

This is difficult to read, because you have to try to follow
the transformation of 1 vertical list into 2 horizontal lists appended to
eachother. An approach that uses 3 columns - 

    col_a -> a -> a \n
    col_b -> b -> b \n

etc. seems more maintainable because you could easily track each variable's transformations.

Comment: @swoogles - Point is, you're not going to make a mistake.  The documentation and following-of-the-transformation all happens in the vertical list.  The rest just needs to have the same number of elements.

Comment: @swoogles If you have many tables with 15+ columns, perhaps normalizing or partitioning your data is in order. Then you could compose multiple parsers into one.